# How to remove light shadow border when blending 2 images using cv2?

Tags: python, image, opencv, alphablending

I have tried to blending 2 images together using cv2 but get a strange border with different color.
The result image has strange yellow border between light and dark area. How can I remove it?
This is the code I'm using to blend them together:

```
land = cv2.imread(land_path)
land = cv2.cvtColor(land, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
land = land.astype(float)
h, w, c = land.shape

sky = cv2.imread(sky_path)
sky = cv2.cvtColor(sky, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
sky = cv2.resize(sky, (w, h))
sky = sky.astype(float)

mask = cv2.imread(mask_path)
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (w, h))
mask = mask.astype(float)/255

sky = cv2.multiply(mask, sky)
land = cv2.multiply(1.0 - mask, land)
result = cv2.add(sky, land)
cv2.imwrite(result_path, result[:, :, ::-1])
```

Original images:

[image: Landscape]

[image: Sky]

[image: Mask image]

The result I got:

[image: Blending result]

Comment: the mask is not exactly black and white, so yellowish sky from the original image gets mixed into the final picture. You might get better results by binarizing the mask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. Your problem is the mask you are using. It should be from the sky image to avoid attenuation from the region just above the horizon. The bright areas in your mask just above the horizon, when negated, cause attenuation of the sunset giving you the dark areas.

```
 - Read the land and sky images
 - Make a version of the sky image as gray
 - Convert both the float
 - Threshold the gray sky image and antialias by blurring and making black anything below 128.
 - Convert mask to float in range 0 to 1 and make it 3 channels.
 - Do the blending
 - Save the result
```

Land Image:

[image]

Sky Image:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read land image and convert to float
land = cv2.imread("land.jpg")
land = land.astype(np.float32)
h, w, c = land.shape

# read sky image, crop to same size as previous image, convert copy to gray, convert sky image to float
sky = cv2.imread("sky.jpg")
sky = sky[0:h, 0:w]
gray_sky = cv2.cvtColor(sky, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sky = sky.astype(np.float32)

# make mask by thresholding sky image, antialias, convert to float in range 0 to 1 and make 3 channels
mask = cv2.threshold(gray_sky, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0,0), 3, 3)
mask[mask<128] = 0
mask = mask.astype(np.float32)/255
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# blend and convert back to 8-bit result
result = land * (1 - mask) + sky * mask
result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("land_sky.jpg", result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dark region around the moon maybe. Adding something like `mask[mask<20] = 0` maybe help you.
edit: Or you can use opencv's [alpha blending](https://www.learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/)
Or maybe something called poison blending can help you. Doing a quick google search I found this [repo](https://github.com/sairamkolla/poison_image_blending).